# Playing video in custom size screen - view in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiview, mpmovieplayercontroller

Suppose user taps on a button and video begins to play. Now when video plays, it always in full screen mode.

Video should be played in a portrait mode (but normally video is played in landscape mode). How can I do this?

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347395/embedded-video-in-a-uiview-with-iphone

Comment: OK. HERE MY requirement is just to play video in portrait mode. Check out my New edited question.

Comment: Question might be duplicate. But Answer isn't duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@interface MPMoviePlayerController (extend) 
 -(void)setOrientation:(int)orientation animated:(BOOL)value; 
@end 

moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieUR]; 
[moviePlayer setOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait animated:NO]; 
if (moviePlayer) 
{ 
    [self.moviePlayer play]; 
}
```

This Solution will be rejected by Apple, as setOrientation for movie player is the Private API. You need to be careful, but it may work on Jailbroke iPhones.

Answer (score 6):

Just an update, the latest iPhone SDK 3.2+ will now allow the programmers to show the video in any desired size and Orientation, New MPMoviePlayerView is provided, which is a property of MPMoviePlayerController, this view will have the video, which you can add as a subview to your view.

Answer (score 1):

From the documented docs i do not think this is possible using the built in media player

Comment: Can we create Custom Media Player?

Comment: OK. HERE MY requirement is just to play video in portrait mode. Check out my New edited question.

Comment: Please try new MPMoviePlayerController , available in iPhone SDK 3.2+, which allows u to customize, set required size and also change orientation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out. 
I found something new.

```
@interface MPMoviePlayerController (extend)
-(void)setOrientation:(int)orientation animated:(BOOL)value;
@end

moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieUR];
[moviePlayer setOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait animated:NO];
if (moviePlayer)
{
    [self.moviePlayer play];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did. Add NSNotification to notify you when preloading of the video finishes.

```
- (void)playVideoUrl:(NSString *)videoUrl {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:videoUrl];
    MPMoviePlayerController* theMovie=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]   
             initWithContentURL:url]; 
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 

    //MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self                           
                       selector:@selector(myMovieFinishedPreloading:)                                            
                           name:MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification                                                
                         object:theMovie]; 


    // Movie playback is asynchronous, so this method returns immediately. 
    [theMovie play]; 
     }
```

Callback selector:

```
-(void)myMovieFinishedPreloading:(NSNotification*)aNotification  {
    NSArray *windows = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows];

    UIWindow *moviePlayerWindow = nil;
    if ([windows count] > 1) 
    {
        moviePlayerWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    }

    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5);
    transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, -90.0f*M_PI/180.0f);
    [moviePlayerWindow setTransform:transform];

 }
```