# iPhone playing video in custom view: Example Code Please?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video

I'm wanting to put together an application which plays video fullscreen with an interface overlaying it that basically chooses the video that is played underneath it (think 'Gym Babes' but nowhere near as risqé!). I don't wish to use private headers so MPMoviePlayerController is out of the question.

I've been digging through stackoverflow for a while and have come to the conclusion that I would need to use some sort of custom codec/video library that I assume would be written in C.

My question is basically has anyone had success doing this? And can anyone share any code, tutorials etc they can share?

Comment: i think below link will be helpful for you...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422930/playing-video-in-custom-size-screen-view-in-iphone

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to take a look at AVPlayerLayer: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerLayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html it gives you basic playback abilities with no (read fully customizable) interface…