# iphone video application

Tags: iphone

i need to play the video through the application in iphone any one is having the sample code or any tutorial for this. i got the same question in the stackoverflow but i didnt get the answer from that question. Here's [iPhone playing video in custom view: Example Code Please?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437983/iphone-playing-video-in-custom-view-example-code-please) any one having the answer for the question.

for this any api is followed tat api will approved by the app store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/mediaplayer-framework_mpmovieplayercontroller_ios4/

http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/how-to-play-video-in-iphoneos4/

For more details about the class you can refer iOS developer library document  [MPMoviePlayerController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: thanks patel.rohn i will check this for further clarification can i ask u.

Comment: hi patel.john i need some clarification abt downloading. i downloaded a zip file and saving the file with static name but i need to store the file with actual name and the extension can u have any tutorial for this..